# WebStorm editor acts unusual in Quasar project

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, quasar

Suddenly my WebStorm editor acts unusual, and I cant type anything in it.
When I type something it just disappears right away. I tried invalidating caches and restarting the program and my computer. See the video below.

Anyone know how to fix it or what I might have done to make it like this?
https://imgur.com/a/N0XyI0Q

Comment: Start with this: 1) Check for any related exceptions/errors logged in the `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in XXX`) 2) Disable all custom (not bundled by default plugins and restart the IDE --- any difference? 3) Does it appear in another (simple) project?